# Conversion of logic formula into algebraic formula

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, ra.rings-and-algebras, computability-theory

We know  formula of boolean algebra in canonical disjunctive normal form has or may be converted to [Zhegalkin polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhegalkin_polynomial).

Is there any approach to convert first order formula into algebraic function or other functions?

Comment: I am also interested in finding connections between logic and algebraic geometry.  The transition from propositional logic to predicate logic can be achieved via "fibration" over a base category, this theory is explained in the book "Categorical logic and type theory" [Jacobs 1999].  Cylindric algebra is a special example of such a fibration, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tarski's [cylindric algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindric_algebra) are an algebraization of first-order logic with equality.

Comment: So we can connect the first order logic to geometry by cylindric algebras, have c.e. idea ,NPC idea of geometry?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Are you assuming that the word "cylindric" refers to geometry?

Comment: No, by algebraization of first-order logic with equality, every formula may be connected to an geometry by the equation (the zeros of the equation) converted from first-order logic formula.

Comment: You know, algebraic geometry is the bridge

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you have in mind. Not everything that has equations is algebraic geometry. There's a difference between making empty analogies and proving theorems.

Comment: Let me think about it and find concrete example to clarify what I have in mind. Actually, I think algebraic geometry is a bridge by which we can extend or generalize the approach. To do so , possibly we can find some problems in the two fields have been solved in other one.

Comment: Sometime, I feel uncomfortable with the approach by which computer scientists solve problem.

Comment: If you're looking for connections between logic and algebraic geoemtry, you could also consider looking into algebraic complexity theory (unless you think that complexity theory is dirty computer science).

Comment: Thank you very much, and i have run into some complexity problem which possibly is related to algebraic complexity.